# How do I reliably count the number of matches in a Datalist based on Input value?

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I have a populated `datalist` element associated with an `input` element to enable native autocompletion features on modern browsers:

**HTML code**

```
<input type="search" id="search" list="autocomplete" />

<datalist id="autocomplete">
    <option value="c++" />
    <option value="javascript" />
    <option value="html" />
    <option value="php" />
</datalist>
```

Using JavaScript, what is a ***reliable*** way of counting the number of matches based on the value of `#search` input? The reason I'm asking this is because processing the autocomplete is a native browser feature, and I anticipate multiple algorithms for selecting a match between vendors.

I don't need to copy or mimick the algorithm of each browser, I just need to find a way to tell how many the browser selected.

A simple `indexOf()` call produces seemingly reliable results, but I couldn't find any resource using which I could ensure it is accurate - also, depending on the browser, you might see differences between the value of `n_matches` and the number of actual options displayed:

**JavaScript**

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].value.indexOf(search.value) !== -1)
        n_matches++;
}
```

[Working demo on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ndsqb1up/)

I know most of you folks might use jQuery or another library for this task, but I'd rather stick to the newfound native approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your current solution gives you some false results. If you type in the letter `a`, your loop will show 5 results, but 0 options will display. `indexOf()` is counting javascript, java, visual basic, chapel, and charm.

So instead of using `indexOf()`, change it to use `charAt(0)`. With [charAt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp) we'll compare the first letter of the search input to the first letter of the possible options.

```
if (options[i].value.charAt(0) === this.value.charAt(0))
```

This gives you an accurate & reliable count to the number of options that will show.

Here is your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/qxezx35s/1/).

I tested in Chrome & IE. You get the same results.

---

**Update** - bug found

```
Search     Results    Options
a            0
h            1          html
j            2          javascript, java
javascript   2          javascript
```

So we can see the last result is incorrect. So we'll want to use your original solution & mine. This will prevent the final scenario in the above table.

```
if (options[i].value.charAt(0) === this.value.charAt(0) && options[i].value.indexOf(this.value) !== -1)
```

[Updated solution](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/qxezx35s/3/)

Comment: The approach you suggested seems to count the **correct** number of matches. However, after entering something into the field, and then deleting it will result in the counter displaying `0` with the dropdown still having the results from the last _non-empty_ match displayed in chrome, and displaying everything from the list in IE.

Comment: By deleting it, are you actually hitting the backspace? or using the `x` to clear things out? If I delete things, the dropdown doesn't show at all. If I hit the `x`, the dropdown remains. But I think that is more expected behavior for `datalists`.

Comment: As for IE, it seems that is how IE has chosen to implement it. If we remove JavaScript and just have the HTML `datalist`, things still behave this way. 
So it's not something that is affected by my solution or yours.

Comment: If you wish to change these browser features, you'll have to create a new question I think.

Comment: Anyways, applying a **minimum character count** check before the conditionally executed statements seems to accurately, and more importantly, _reliably_ solve the problem. The start-based substring match was a good call, I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but, I had issues with both solutions. Both solutions above either returned the correct number only part of the time or just kept returning 0 as the options were narrowed down. The solution that worked for me is actually seeing if any of the options contains the search criteria as it narrows down the results.

```
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].value.toLowerCase().includes(search.value.toLowerCase()))
        n_matches++;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In addition to sharing your code you should consider elaborating further on why your solution is better than the existing (and accepted) one(s) and which problems you were facing with them. This might help others users who have your same issue in the future.